# How effective is Deep Sleep Mode?

Tags: macos, sleep-wake, macbook-pro

I got frustrated from turning on my Retina MBP and waiting a few seconds while the systems  loads from Deep Sleep Mode.

I disabled it using `sudo pmset -a standby 0`

However, I would like to know what I am missing now. Will I start losing a lot of battery power while the laptop is sleeping normally (basically not in Deep Sleep Mode) ?

For example, in 1 hour (or 2-5 hours), how much percentage will battery I lose on Sleep mode, and how much would I lose when its in Deep Sleep Mode ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your Mac might last a week in sleep where it might last a month in deep sleep.

If you travel with a power adapter or would rather end up with no battery than wait a few seconds longer each wake, then keep deep sleep turned off.

Comment: I used _might_ since each battery tends to have slightly different timings and these times are for a fully topped off battery - most sleep events start with less than a full charge - sometimes substantially less charge than full.

Comment: If I only take it out of the charger to go study in a library thats 10 minutes away. Then stay there for a few hours and come back to stick it back in. Would Deep Sleep Mode be necessary ?

Comment: You could do the measurements, but the current draw difference between sleep and deep sleep is going to be unmeasurable for a sleep duration of less than 5 hours so unless you are regularly keeping it in sleep, in a bag, away from power for days at a time, I wouldn't worry about things.

Answer (score 5):

The 13-inch MacBook Pro with Retina Display has a 74 watt-hour battery. It uses about 0.86W in sleep mode and 0.30W when off (or in [standby mode](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT4392)), which translates to about 3.6 and 10.3 days.

Standby mode is only enabled after 70 minutes of normal sleep, so there won't be any difference after an hour. After that, normal sleep would use about 1.2% of the maximum capacity per hour and standby mode about 0.4%.

If you paid 0.15 USD per kilowatt hour for electricity and kept the MacBook Pro in sleep mode (with standby mode disabled) for 15 hours per day, it would cost about 0.70 USD per year.

Power Nap might increase power consumption, but it's not enabled on battery power.