# Why there are two sleep modes?

Tags: sleep-wake

I am quite confused, I close the lid and then my mac book pro goes sleep and sometimes it seems to be in deep sleep and sometime it is not. I mean, sometimes when you open the lid, it will recover soon with a log-in window showing up quickly, sometimes it will show a white screen and a recovering progress bar at the bottom and then a few minutes later the log-in window.

What's the theory behind this? How can I prevent it from going to deep sleep mode? Thanks

Comment: What version of OS X are you running?

Comment: I think it is the newest one. I just bought it

Comment: This question would be more valuable if the MacOS version was specified. Years later, "the latest" is not useful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The theory behind it is that it gets a lot more battery life when in deep sleep/hibernation than otherwise. Apple says after about an hour the computer should go into deep sleep.

See [this question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/75408/how-effective-is-deep-sleep-mode) for further information and how to disable it. (The actual disabling instructions are in the question itself.)

Answer (score 3):

Also note that if you close the lid and you have a low battery charge that it may go low enough while closed that it stores the ram state to the HDD. This is so that when you reconnect to a power source and wake it up anything that you had opened will be restored as it was. This process takes time because you are basically reading 2-4 gigs worth of information back into the ram before it becomes stable enough to resume.